# Can you embed VLC on a website so that people who doesn't have VLC installed can view it?

Tags: html, video, web, streaming, vlc

I am trying to make a video streaming site and I want to use VLC to play my video. However, I want other people who doesn't have VLC to be able to view my videos through a VLC plugin. Is it possible? I want to use VLC because it can play anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewer has to have VLC and the Browser Plugin Installed on there pc, depending on the file format of the video you could use the HTML5 Video tag.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
Update your browser.
</video>
```

This will only work if the viewer has a html5 ready browser meaning old versions of IE wont be able to see the video but the code will tell them that they have to update there browser

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to avoid Video tags since they have limited Video File support. The reason I want VLC to work is because no matter what type of video someone upload onto my site, it'll be played and VLC is the only player that can support that. Such as FLV, Webm, mp4, avi, wmv, mkv, rmvb...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout the current beta of http://www.projekktor.com - it's a generic HTML 5 player, which uses whatever backend is available on the user's PC. Since recently, it also supports VLC: https://twitter.com/projekktor/status/354187957571297281